# Differentiate embedded "<img src='http://example.com/xxx.jpg'>" and direct "http://example.com/xxx.jpg"?

Tags: image, .htaccess

Is it possible to differntiate between an embedded HTTP request to an image as in `<img src='http://example.com/xxx.jpg'>` and a direct image access as in `http://example.com/xxx.jpg`?

I do a htaccess redirect using `HTTP_REFERER` in case a request comes from outside my domain to add a water sign to the pictures. Only in case of a direct access, I'd like in addition show a HTML page with some hints.

I used `HTTP_ACCEPT` for that. When it started with `image/` then it was an embedded access. Otherwise it was a direct access. This does not work anymore. I always get `*/*`.

Any idea how to achieve that (in PHP)?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, no idea how to be more specific...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way that should work in most modern Browsers, but there is no quarantine. Because Browsers tend so send a HTTP header called "referer" if a resource is requested, we could select based on this. So if the referer is equal to your domain than we have no direct access.

```
# Check if the URI is a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -f
# Check if the file has any kind off Image extension like:
# .gif .jpg .jpeg .tif .tiff .png .svg .bmp (case insensitive => [NC])
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpe?g|tiff?|png|svg|bmp)$ [NC]
# Check if referer is empty
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" ^$ [NC]
# Direct  access
RewiteRule ^.*$ /direct_access.html [L]

# Check if the URI is a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -f
# Check if the file has any kind off Image extension like:
# .gif .jpg .jpeg .tif .tiff .png .svg .bmp (case insensitive => [NC])
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpe?g|tiff?|png|svg|bmp)$ [NC]
# Check if referer is not own domain
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
# External access
RewiteRule ^.*$ /image_water_sign.php [L]
```

This works for www and non-www as well for http and https just change `example\.com` to your e.g. `domain\.org`
The RewiteRules  are just examples.

Just one Remark: This is not a absolute protection if you want to protect your images from direct download. Faking the HTTP header with this data is very simple.

Comment: Well, I'm using `HTTP_REFERER` already. Otherwise the above mentioned redirect (_`I do a htaccess redirect in case a request comes from outside my domain`_) would not work. I want to differentiate embedded and direct access if a request comes from outside my domain. Differentiate between outside and inside is easy...

Comment: If someone enter the Image URL direct into the Browser %{HTTP_REFERER} will be not-set/empty

Comment: Finally I accept this answer as it covers most of the cases. An embedded & empty referer request (e.g. referer actively disabled in browser)  would not be handled properly but is very rare... Thank you very much!

Comment: This is why i say "there is no quarantine"